# Getting a list of values from dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm beginner in c#, and I'm trying to get a list of values but I get a null object reference.

I have a dictionary

```
var stripes = new Dictionary<int, List<Transform>>();
```

and I'm trying to get the list of transforms

```
       foreach (var stripe in stripes)
            {
                List<Transform> transforms = stripe.Value;
                foreach (var treeTransform in transforms)
                {
                    float distance = DistanceToCameraPlane(treeTransform.position);
                    TreeObject treeObject = new TreeObject();
                    treeObject.distance = distance;
                    treeObject.tree = treeTransform;
                    sortedTrees.Add(treeObject);
                }
            }
```

However I get a null object references in `treeTransform.position`

Comment: Your problem is not iterating your dictionary, your problem is that the value added to the dictionary is null and when you try to used it throw a null reference exception.

Comment: you should check why you have `null` elements inside your transforms collection. Since you get the `NullReferenceException` on the `treeTransform.position` line, which means `treeTransform` is null somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
foreach (var stripe in stripes)
```

to this instead:

```
foreach (List<Transform> transforms in stripes.Values)
```

and remove this:

```
List<Transform> transforms = stripe.Value;
```

Comment: Consider explaining why that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var stripe in stripes)
            {
                List<Transform> transforms = stripe.Value;
                if (transforms != null && transforms.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var treeTransform in transforms)
                    {
                        if (treeTransform != null)
                        {
                            float distance = DistanceToCameraPlane(treeTransform.position);
                            TreeObject treeObject = new TreeObject();
                            treeObject.distance = distance;
                            treeObject.tree = treeTransform;
                            sortedTrees.Add(treeObject);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Adding the null checks was the first thing I thought too.